# One particular permutation $\sigma $ of $5$ elements such that $\sigma ^{-1} (j) \le \sigma (j)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

As  for  options  $1.$  and  $2.$  I  have  taken  a  few  examples  randomly and  found  them  to  be  correct  but  could  not  generalize  and I am  clueless  about options $3.$  and  $4.$ The  answer   keys  that  came  with   it  says  all  the  options   are  correct.

Comment: Hint: "Induction" on $\sigma(j)$ is one route to prove 2. This implies that $\sigma^2$ is the identity mapping (part 1) and the rest follows.

Comment: Use text instead of images:  it makes viewing the page faster and improves the ability to be searched.  Read [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/18398) to learn how to use MathJax, then [edit] your post to replace the image with your text in MathJax.

Answer (score 2):

For $2$., sum the inequality over all $j$. Then both sides are equal, so equality must hold for all $j$.

$2$. implies $1$. by the definition of $\sigma^{-1}$.

$3$. and $4$. imply each other, since the total number of elements is odd (namely $5$).

For $3$., note that $\sigma(k)=\sigma^{-1}(k)$ implies that the elements that $\sigma$ doesn't leave invariant come in pairs.

Comment: How can we use your hint to prove 2. I am not able to see it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ShwetaAggrawal: If you sum the given inequality over all $j$, since $\sigma$ and $\sigma^{-1}$ are bijections you get each element once on each side. Thus both sides of the sum are the sum of all elements, so they're equal. If you sum over weak inequalities and you get an equality, each of the weak inequalities must individually be an equality, since if one of them were a strict inequality, the sum would also be a strict inequality.